# Yii2 Custom filter Dropdown for gridview

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to add a custom filter named **Sort By Month** in the grid view header here is an example of the previous version of the site which I am revamping see below image[image]

I was looking into the `layout` option of the grid view and added a drop-down in the layout template before `{items}`

```
GridView::widget(
        [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'layout' => '{summary}{errors}' . \kartik\widgets\Select2::widget(
                [
                    'model' => $searchModel,
                    'attribute' => 'filter_month',
                    'theme' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::THEME_DEFAULT,
                    'data' => $searchModel->getFilterMonths(),
                    'pluginEvents' => [
                        "select2:select" => 'function() { $("#w2").submit();}',
                        //  'select2:select'=> new \yii\web\JsExpression("function(){console.log('here')}"),
                    ],
                    'options' => [
                        'placeholder' => '--Select Month--',
                    ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true,
                        'width' => '160px',
                    ],
                ]
            ) . '{items}{pager}',
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'name',
                'title',
                'catalog',
                'upc_code',
                [
                    'attribute' => 'created_on',
                    'label' => 'Created On',
                    'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget(['dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'model' => $searchModel, 'attribute' => 'created_on']),
                    'format' => 'html',
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'status',
                    'label' => 'Status',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'value' => function ($data) {
                        switch ($data->status) {
                            case 0:
                                return "Being Edited    (" . $data->created_on . ")";
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                return ($data->maxdate == '') ? 'Active' : 'Active';
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                return "Expired";
                                break;
                        }
                    },
                ],
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            ],
        ]
);
```

Now I want to submit the filters form when I select an option from the drop-down, but could not figure out how to attach the default filter submit event with the drop-down options so that it filters the results when I select any option in the drop-down.

Comment: Please use t

"filterSelector" => "#". Html::getInputId($searchModel, 'AttributeName'),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Custom filter you have used the perfect layout but you have to provide your custom field as a `filterSelector`.

```
"filterSelector" => "#". Html::getInputId($searchModel, 'AttributeName'),
```

Comment: Thanks @ieatbytes you were right it started working like a charm.